# Picture not fit to picturebox c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, picturebox

I am actually working with PictureBox on .NET, then I face the problem below:

- I create a PictureBox of size 370 x 370 with mode size "Normal"
- I have a picture .png of size 370 x 370 (pixel)
- Then I create a button to import the picture to the picturebox via OpenFileDialog
- I run the app, then I click the button and I choose my picture

! Problem: My picture is not fit to my picturebox. Why ?

[image: link to the screenshot]

Comment: That picturebox is not 370x370.  And there is a probable mismatch in the dots-per-inch between the image and the form.  Set the PictureBox.SizeMode property and [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).

Comment: The SizeMode looks like Tiled. Note that you should have set the ClientSize to allow for a border not the (outer) Size.

Comment: @HansPassant: I added the file "Application Manifest File" to my project and uncommented dpiAware then it worked !!! Thanks